# if group by sequence is not same , aggregated values are not same

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Below given are three queries, which are used to get the aggregated data from a table user_
daily_achievements. All of them are same apart from only sequence in group by part.

```
select sum(jsm_amount) from (
select date,user_id,distributor_id,sum(user_daily_achievements.invoiced_amount) as jsm_amount from user_daily_achievements where date>='2020-06-01' and date<'2020-07-01'
group by date,user_id,distributor_id)a;

select sum(jsm_amount) from (
select date,distributor_id,user_id,sum(user_daily_achievements.invoiced_amount) as jsm_amount from user_daily_achievements where date>='2020-06-01' and date<'2020-07-01'
group by date,distributor_id,user_id)a;

select sum(jsm_amount) from (
select distributor_id,user_id,date,sum(user_daily_achievements.invoiced_amount) as jsm_amount from user_daily_achievements where date>='2020-06-01' and date<'2020-07-01'
group by distributor_id,user_id,date)a;
```

As per my understanding, total amount should be same for all three cases. But I am getting different values in each query.

Database: Posgtres
Version : 11

Comment: Yes, the values should be the same.  What are the two values?

Comment: I am getting these three values in three different queries : 518547264,  518547008 and 518546848

Comment: The discrepancies you are seeing are most likely just due to rounding errors.

Comment: thanks it seems round off error

Answer (score 1):

I converted values before processing to numeric. This works.

```
select sum(jsm_amount) from (
select date,user_id,distributor_id,sum(user_daily_achievements.invoiced_amount::numeric) as jsm_amount from user_daily_achievements where date>='2020-06-01' and date<'2020-07-01'
group by date,user_id,distributor_id)a;

select sum(jsm_amount) from (
select date,distributor_id,user_id,sum(user_daily_achievements.invoiced_amount::numeric) as jsm_amount from user_daily_achievements where date>='2020-06-01' and date<'2020-07-01'
group by date,distributor_id,user_id)a;

select sum(jsm_amount) from (
select distributor_id,user_id,date,sum(user_daily_achievements.invoiced_amount::numeric) as jsm_amount from user_daily_achievements where date>='2020-06-01' and date<'2020-07-01'
group by distributor_id,user_id,date)a;
```

Comment: Good answer, you have just proven (more or less) that the problem was rounding error due to floating point arithmetic.